# How to Adjust Classification Threshold with a Spark Decision Tree

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree

I'm using Spark 2.0 and the new spark.ml. packages.
Is there a way to adjust the classification threshold so that I reduce the number of False Positives.
If it matters I'm also using the CrossValidator.

I see RandomForestClassifier and DecisionTreeClassifier both output a probability column (Which I could use manually, but GBTClassifier does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for the [`thresholds`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier@thresholds:org.apache.spark.ml.param.DoubleArrayParam) parameter:

> `final val thresholds: DoubleArrayParam`
>
> Param for Thresholds in multi-class classification to adjust the probability 
>   of predicting each class. Array must have length equal to the number of 
>   classes, with values >= 0. The class with largest value p/t is predicted, 
>   where p is the original probability of that class and t is the class' 
>   threshold.

You will need to set it by calling `setThresholds(value: Array[Double])` on your classifier.

Comment: I will check, but I note that GBT doesn't have this, but RandomForest and DecisionTree does.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Unfortunately it looks like you're out of luck with the `GBTClassifier` for now. Judging from the [implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5ec0d692b0789a1d06db35134ee6eac2ecce47c3/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/GBTClassifier.scala), it looks like the Spark ML version wraps the older MLlib version, which lacks the [`ProbabilisticClassifier`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifier).

Comment: In Spark 2.2 GBTClassifier has setThresholds parameter. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.GBTClassifier

Comment: @Maziyar is it Spark 2.2 or 2.4+ ?
Is there any implementation regarding this in PySpark?

Comment: @Rudr Yes, they have it in 2.2: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.GBTClassifier
Unfortunately, I couldn't find this in PySpark even in 2.4.3:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.GBTClassifier